# Instance cache cleanup

Tags: java, caching, pool

I have an object/class ClassA, whose instances need to be cached(let's call it cache1) with thousands of keys.
But actually the instance count of ClassA is limited to hundreds.

So I want to squeeze the heap usage of the cache by reusing instances of ClassA.

A simple way to do that is to use a simple pool(maybe this isn't a common pool):

```
final class ClassA {

    private byte[] bytes;
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ClassA> instancePool = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private ClassA(String bigString) {
        bytes = bigString.getBytes();
    }

    public static ClassA getInstance(String key) {
        instancePool.putIfAbsent(key, new ClassA(key));
        return instancePool.get(key);
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

It works. But the problems is the instances can change, even not frequently.
The cache can expire, but not the `instancePool`. So it will hold more and more useless instances, which looks like a time bomb to me.

So I want to clear useless(not ref by cache1) instances from the pool. 
A simple idea is to use another cache(cache2) rather than the instancePool. And give it much longer expiry time. But it seems not an ideal way.

This seems to be a common problem. Any lib to do this?

Comment: Your cache should not hold strong references but `WeakReference` of its instances. Then Java can delete them as soon as no one is using them anymore (the cache then does not count as "user"). Then let it frequently delete items that do not exist anymore for cleanup (`WeakReference` provides a method to test if its still there or was deleted already by Java).

Comment: This is a XY problem. There are better ways to achieve what you want (see above comment) than what you propose as solution.

Comment: I agree WeakReference is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expire the object based on time you can use [ExpiringMap](https://jodah.net/expiringmap/javadoc/net/jodah/expiringmap/ExpiringMap.html) from jodah.

Like:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = ExpiringMap.builder().expiration(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to point to the problems in implementation:

1. `String` is immutable, therefore `byte[] bytes` could be final and encapsulated in the `ClassA`
2. `getBytes()` brakes OOP encapsulation principle. It should retrieve a copy of `byte[] bytes`.
3. `instancePool.putIfAbsent(key, new ClassA(key));` you create here a new instance of `ClassA` every time, even if it exists and will not be put into the cache.
4. `ClassA getInstance(String key)` in case of `key` is a big `String`, then why do you create a copy of internal `byte[]`? why not just use `String` itself and use `key.charAt()`?
5. `bytes = bigString.getBytes();` uses `Charset cs = Charset.defaultCharset();` so you could get a surprise if the `key` contains not ASCII characters.

It's not good to retrieve `byte[] bytes` itself as well as not good to make a copy every time when `getBytes()` is invoked. Therefore, I recommend you to use **immutable** object. In this case, you're not going to have a problem with items' expiration, because every time when the should be changed, you remove this item from the cache.

I am thinking smth. about like this:

```
public final class ClassA {

    private static final Map<UUID, ClassA> POOL = new HashMap<>();

    private final UUID id;
    private final byte[] data;

    public static synchronized ClassA getInstance(UUID id, byte[] data) {
        if (POOL.containsKey(id))
            return POOL.get(id);

        ClassA obj = new ClassA(id, data);
        POOL.put(id, obj);
        return obj;
    }

    private ClassA(UUID id, byte[] data) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public byte getByteAt(int pos) {
        return data[pos];
    }

}
```

Comment: Most of your comments are valid. I didn't polish the code much because it's not my main question.